# Java optimization and minimization

Tags: optimization, java

I'm new to optimization and I have a little problem that I want to resolve with my job. Here we go!

I need a certain number of drivers per day and each driver has 2 consecutive days off during the week. My optimization problem is that I want to have as few employees as possible with the number of driver per week. I need guidance please

For example, I need 6 drivers Monday, 5 drivers Tuesday, 8 drivers Wednesday, 5 drivers Thursday and 6 drivers Friday

The final result should look like this:
[image]

sSo the optimization function has to return 4 drivers with Monday and Tuesday off, 1 driver with Wednesday and Thursday, 1 driver with WT and 4 drivers with TF. That's a small sample, but I have more days to cover than that

I tried randomly, I tried with a method that I thought was good but wasn't. So the main problem is, with different number of drivers required per day (Monday to Friday) I want to have the least number of drivers required per week. An other example: I need 7 drivers on monday, 3 drivers on tuesday, 3 drivers on wednesday, 6 drivers on thursday and 8 drivers on friday

The result should be : I need 2 driver with monday tuesday off, 4 drivers with tuesday wednesday off, 2 drivers with wednesday and thursday off and 1 driver with thursday friday off. You can see with the tab below:
[image]

I don't need code, I just need to know how to start

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "as few employees as possible with the number of driver per week"?  I don't understand what is the difference between the number of employees vs the number of drivers.

Comment: the number of drivers is the number (who is always different each week) needed each day. In the last example, i need 7 drivers for Monday,  3 drivers on Tuesday, etc... the number of employees is the number of weekly guide I will get by my optimization result. A weekly guide must have 2 days off consecutively. If you get a look in the tab, a weekly guide is a row and each row is an different employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with linear programming.

Let's start with the variables.  Let $x_d$ denote the number of drivers whose work week starts on day $d$, e.g., $x_\text{Monday}$ denotes the number of drivers who work Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, and have Saturday and Sunday off.

Next the inequalities.  Each requirement gives you a linear inequality on the above variables.  For instance, if you want at least 6 drivers on Monday, then you need to have

$$x_\text{Mon} + x_\text{Thu} + x_\text{Fri} + x_\text{Sat} + x_\text{Sun} \ge 6.$$

Also, the number of drivers on each day must be at least zero, so we have $x_\text{Mon} \ge 0$, $x_\text{Tue} \ge 0$, etc.

Finally, the objective function.  You say you want to minimize the number of employees, so you should minimize

$$\Phi = x_\text{Mon} + x_\text{Tue} + x_\text{Wed} + x_\text{Thu} + x_\text{Fri} + x_\text{Sat} + x_\text{Sun}.$$

Your goal is to minimize $\Phi$, subject to the above linear inequalities.  This is an instance of linear programming, so you can provide it as input to an off-the-shelf LP solver, and it will give you an optimal solution.

You might need to adjust this if you want to allow drivers who take more than two days off during the week, and/or if you want to have a secondary goal of minimizing the number of days per week worked by the drivers.

In general your problem might be considered to fall within the area of operations research, so you can learn more about methods used in operations research (which includes linear programming, integer linear programming, and other methods).

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help and time. I will focus on linear programming !

Comment: @Maxime, you're welcome!  I revised my answer (see next-to-last paragraph) regarding a detail I just noticed.

Comment: Yes, if the total numbers of drivers needed per day int the week is not a multiple of 3 , somes drivers will have 3 days off in the week, but must be consecutive. No driver have days off in the week end

Comment: Hi just have a little question. I need 6 drivers mnimum for monday, why in your equation you didn't put Tuesday and Wednesday? xMon+xThu+xFri+xSat+xSun≥6.

Comment: @Maxime, because drivers who work Tue-Sat (xTue) have Monday off, and drivers who work Wed-Sun (xWed) have Monday off.  Hopefully you get the main idea and you can formulate your own LP instance based on the exact details of your specific instance.